# Overflow on <div> won't work inside a bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have tried fixing this for about an hour to no avail. I have a  element inside a bootstrap popover that I want to be 300px in height. This div element will display a paragraph and scroll if the content is longer than 300px in height. Here is a screen shot of what it looks like now.
[image]

As you can see the description is too long. I have HTML and CSS that is supposed to make this a scrollable window.

```
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-sm p-0 m-0"
  data-bs-toggle="popover"
  data-bs-trigger="focus"
  data-bs-html="true"
  data-bs-container="body"
  data-bs-content="@BuildPopover(skill)">
    <i class='fa-regular fa-lightbulb text-dark font-sm p-0'></i>
 </button>
```

This button above defines this to generate a popover when clicked. The BuildOver function builds an HTML element that will be displayed. Here is that element. I have truncated the element. (I tested this truncated and this description still doesn't get displayed as scrolled)

```
<div class='header-sans-serif font-lg font-weight-bold text-center p-3 bordered rounded mb-3'>SkillName Goes Here</div>
    <div class='row header-sans-serif'>
        <div class='col-4'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-8 text-justify'>
            <div class='font-weight-bold'>Description</div>
            <div class='font-weight-normal' style='height:300px;overflow:auto;'>Long description goes here</div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried setting !important on all style elements. I have a max-height in my stylesheet for .popover. I have a max height in my stylesheet for .popover-body and .popover-main.

This still won't work. What else am I missing?